# Is there any way I can auto backup config file to github?

Tags: git, bash, sublimetext2, backup, oh-my-zsh

I want to automatically backup my .zshrc file and some sublime setting files to Github.

I think there is two ways to do this:

1. Detect file changes, when a file changes, pushed it to Github immediately.
2. Stage files by a fixed time period, like one day one backup.

Is there a graceful and specific way？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this [gitwatch project](https://github.com/nevik/gitwatch) which uses inotifywait to detect change and git add / commit / push to remote

You can then create a background service executing this script with the required parameters triggered on boot